# Find when value changes one row based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to find the next row in one column where the value changes, based on a check on another column

```
df[(df['Col1'] == 49.8) & (df['Col2'] != 0) & (df['Col2'].abs() > 0.02)]
```

The code above produces results, which is ok, but the value in Col3 change sometime later

So , how do I use the result of the code above to search when the Col3 changes?

Below is an excerpt of my dataframe

My python code returns the following

```
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.413000 | 49.8 | 39.8 | 0    |
```

But I want to be able to show

```
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.413000 | 49.8 | 39.8 | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.753000 | 49.8 | 39.8 | 15   |
```

As the goal is to find the time difference between the two

Edit based on first answer

Sorry, I explained it incorreclty, and had my example a little wrong. col2 is the amount that col1 changes per row. See below, when col2 is not bigger than 0.02 as per my python code then ignore the change.

```
| Datetime                   | Col1  | Col2 | Col3 |
|----------------------------|-------|------|------|
|  23-02-03 12:01:27.213000  | 10    | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.243000 | 10    | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.313000 | 10    | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.353000 | 10    | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.413000 | 49.8  | 39.8 | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.453000 | 49.8  | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.513000 | 49.8  | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.553000 | 49.8  | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.613000 | 49.8  | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.653000 | 49.8  | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.713000 | 49.8  | 0    | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.753000 | 49.8  | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.813000 | 49.8  | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.853000 | 49.8  | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.913000 | 49.8  | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.953000 | 49.8  | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.013000 | 49.81 | 0.1  | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.053000 | 49.81 | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.113000 | 49.82 | 0.1  | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.153000 | 49.82 | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.213000 | 59.8  | 9.98 | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.253000 | 59.8  | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.313000 | 59.8  | 0    | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.353000 | 59.8  | 0    | 25   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.423000 | 59.8  | 0    | 25   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.453000 | 59.8  | 0    | 25   |
```

So the result would be

```
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.413000 | 49.8  | 39.8 | 0    |
| 23-02-03   12:01:27.753000 | 49.8  | 0    | 15   |
```

And

```
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.213000 | 59.8  | 9.98 | 15   |
| 23-02-03   12:01:28.353000 | 59.8  | 0    | 25   |
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your edit. You want to select the first row where `Col2` has a value > 0.02, and then select the first row after that where `Col3` changes?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes thats correct. I use df['Col1'] == 49.8) to make sure that I select certain values. So I can select 49.8 and 59.8 and other values. So its not always > 0.02. Its 49.8 or 59.8 and > 0.02

Comment: See my updated answer. If the condition is not always `> 0.02`, you can change the `(df["Col2"] > 0.02)` part to reflect that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your dataframe:

```
                  Datetime   Col1   Col2  Col3
0  2003-02-23 12:01:27.213  10.00   0.00     0
1  2003-02-23 12:01:27.243  10.00   0.00     0
2  2003-02-23 12:01:27.313  10.00   0.00     0
3  2003-02-23 12:01:27.353  10.00   0.00     0
4  2003-02-23 12:01:27.413  49.80  39.80     0
5  2003-02-23 12:01:27.453  49.80   0.00     0
6  2003-02-23 12:01:27.513  49.80   0.00     0
7  2003-02-23 12:01:27.553  49.80   0.00     0
8  2003-02-23 12:01:27.613  49.80   0.00     0
9  2003-02-23 12:01:27.653  49.80   0.00     0
10 2003-02-23 12:01:27.713  49.80   0.00     0
11 2003-02-23 12:01:27.753  49.80   0.00    15
12 2003-02-23 12:01:27.813  49.80   0.00    15
13 2003-02-23 12:01:27.853  49.80   0.00    15
14 2003-02-23 12:01:27.913  49.80   0.00    15
15 2003-02-23 12:01:27.953  49.80   0.00    15
16 2003-02-23 12:01:28.013  49.81   0.10    15
17 2003-02-23 12:01:28.053  49.81   0.00    15
18 2003-02-23 12:01:28.113  49.82   0.10    15
19 2003-02-23 12:01:28.153  49.82   0.00    15
20 2003-02-23 12:01:28.213  59.80   9.98    15
21 2003-02-23 12:01:28.253  59.80   0.00    15
22 2003-02-23 12:01:28.313  59.80   0.00    15
23 2003-02-23 12:01:28.353  59.80   0.00    25
24 2003-02-23 12:01:28.423  59.80   0.00    25
25 2003-02-23 12:01:28.453  59.80   0.00    25
```

Let's first extract the rows where `df["Col2"] > 0.02` or the value of `df["Col3"]` has changed, i.e. `df["Col3"].diff() != 0`:

```
df_filt = df[(df["Col2"] > 0.02) | (df["Col3"].diff().fillna(value=0) != 0)]
```

(I added `.fillna(value=0)` to fill the first element with zero.)

```
                  Datetime   Col1   Col2  Col3
4  2003-02-23 12:01:27.413  49.80  39.80     0
11 2003-02-23 12:01:27.753  49.80   0.00    15
16 2003-02-23 12:01:28.013  49.81   0.10    15
18 2003-02-23 12:01:28.113  49.82   0.10    15
20 2003-02-23 12:01:28.213  59.80   9.98    15
23 2003-02-23 12:01:28.353  59.80   0.00    25
```

from this filtered dataframe, we want to select only those rows where the diff is nonzero, and the row prior:

```
diff_nz = df_filt["Col3"].diff().fillna(value=0) != 0

result = df[diff_nz | diff_nz.shift(-1)]
```

which gives the desired result:

```
                  Datetime  Col1   Col2  Col3
4  2003-02-23 12:01:27.413  49.8  39.80     0
11 2003-02-23 12:01:27.753  49.8   0.00    15
20 2003-02-23 12:01:28.213  59.8   9.98    15
23 2003-02-23 12:01:28.353  59.8   0.00    25
```

And since you want to find the difference in time between the rows containing the same `Col1`,

```
delta_t = result.groupby("Col1").diff().dropna()
```

If you want `Col1` back in this dataframe, do:

```
delta_t["Col1"] = result["Col1"]
```

This works because both dataframes have the same indices. The final result is:

```
                 Datetime   Col2  Col3  Col1
11 0 days 00:00:00.340000 -39.80  15.0  49.8
23 0 days 00:00:00.140000  -9.98  10.0  59.8
```

Comment: Thanks let me run this on my machine